# Trying to filter after a sliced queryset

Tags: django, filter, slice, django-queryset

So I'm trying to return the top 4 posts of all the posts, ranked by votes.  But I don't want to return any posts that the user already has loaded on his/her page.  I have an array of the post pk's the user has loaded to check.  But I can't simply exclude posts the query before the slice like this

```
posts = Post.objects.order_by('-votes')
posts = posts.exclude(pk__in = excludePks)
posts = posts[:4]
```

Because then if any of the top 4 posts got excluded, I could get the 5th, 6th, 7th, or 8th top posts returned.

I'd like to only exclude posts in the top 4 if one of the pk's matches a pk in excludePks.

I tried filtering after the slice, but as I found out, that's impossible to do because a slice is equivalent to doing a LIMIT in SQL.

```
posts = Post.objects.order_by('-votes')[:4]
posts = posts.exclude(pk__in = excludePks)
```

Is there a good way to exclude posts in the top four without getting posts below the top 4 returned as a result?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, but since there's only 4 and you're going to need the data afterwards anyways, filter in Python.

```
posts = [post for post in Post.objects.order_by('-votes')[:4]
           if post.pk not in excludePks]
```